# AC Blows air too cold

Tags: hvac, home-automation

This is in response to Matt S's question a few days back. I feel like most of the answers were a put down and I am experiencing the same problem he is. It is not the temperature of the house or where the system cools it to that is the problem. The actual air that blows out is the coldest in the "normal range", as tested by an A/C company, and its freezing to me. Many places in the house that I sit or stand are under a vent. I have owned several houses and additionally rental properties and have never experienced this before. Like the comments here, the overweight AC guy shrugged and said he doesn't hear people complain the AC is too cold. Well, for me it is to the point where I want to put the house up for sale it is so unbearable. If replacing the unit is the only way to solve it I will do it (it is 10 years old), otherwise if someone has a friendly suggestion that isn't "unrealistic expectations" please help. Thanks!

Comment: wanted to stress that it is NOT the temperature of the house that is my problem, it is the ice cold air that blows out.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the vents.   Possibly a problem that was *induced* by a previous owner who liked it that way.

Comment: Blower speed can often be adjusted.

Comment: @Tyson that's more complicated than simply changing the speed.  It's doubtful that the average homeowner has the tools or knowledge, required to determine if  it can be adjusted.

Comment: @DavidTrietiak what about diffusers, or deflectors on the vents?  They could be installed so that the air doesn't blow directly on you.  Would rearranging the furniture be an option?

Comment: Where is this property located? What is the temperature of the air coming out of the vents? The cheapest and easiest way to remediate this condition would be to set the thermostat higher. The blower will run less often and you will have less time with too cold air blowing on you.

Comment: What kind of filter are you using? If the filter is too restrictive it will cause lower air flow and give a lower flow but colder air. A filter which is too restrictive will also cause excessive low pressure at the intake of the blower. This can overload the blower motor leading to a burned out blower motor.

Comment: I don't want to make light of this but I live in Texas where its predicted to reach 100F this week so we don't know too cold. However, you might try to find a ventilation company someone who does air balancing. They might be able to help. The only other thing I can think of is installing a VFD (you're going to need help with that too).

Comment: Let me give blower fan instructions; ( I am not trying to preach, just teach). Reducing the air flow either to or from  the blower, will not overload a squirrel cage blower motor. Restrictive filters, small ,restrictive  duct work lowers the amperage draw of the motor since you are reducing the amount of air the blower is moving. (It's not the other way around). The only way you can overload the blower is with allowing it to move more air, not less air.

Comment: @d.george, I was aware that running squirrel cage fan with a standard motor without the necessary load would ruin the motor. I don't understand this but I certainly accept that it is true. However, I had read that there was a new type of motor or motor controls which would apply more power if the inflow was restricted (as by a clogged filter) to keep constant rpms or flow. The story I read was that if an excessively restrictive filter was used with this type of motor that burn outs could and in fact were occurring. Is this just a false internet story?

Comment: to Jim Stewart; since I retired 10 years ago I am not "up to date" on the latest stuff. People talk about variable speed pumps, fans, etc. that I only saw on large scale commercial and industrial applications using "freek drives". I guess that in order to sell more stuff the manufacturers are pushing companies to sell these items to residential customers. ( stuff that they really do not need).

Comment: @David Trietiak I have the same problem. It blows hard and is freezing in here. Did you ever find a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Air too cold---I would measure the temperature drop across the evaporator coil in the furnace/air handler. If it is more than 20 degrees then moving more across the coil is necessary. Usually this could be done by increasing the blower speed. If you do not know how to do this call a good service tech to help. If the furniture is arranged so the discharge vents blow on you when you are sitting there, then you need to change the way the cold air enters the room or move the furniture. And not to slight Jim but I have never heard of raising the evaporator temperature by adding more refrigerant and overcharging a system has never been a good thing; ( if I am wrong let me apologize in advance). There could be other problems such as the A/C system is too large for the house, not enough supply registers allowing too much air to be discharged from those registers, poor placement of registers, the ducting is too small causing the air velocity to be higher than normal or there is too much air coming from the registers. But first start by measuring the temperature drop across the coil. Hope this helps

Comment: My comment recommending *adding* refrigerant to slightly overcharge was one of those "think outside the box" ideas that are usually wrong but are perhaps thought provoking. You are right to question it and personally I wouldn't do it; I would never use anything but the optimum charge, but I love cold air blowing on me. I sit at the kitchen table right under an a/c vent with 58 F air blowing on me.

Comment: One possibility is that the filter is too restrictive and is restricting the air flow. If someone has put on a "special" filter designed to stop small particulate matter this might be reducing the flow rate. A filter which is too resistive to air flow can shorten the life of the blower motor by overloading it.

Answer (score 0):

actually your ac is a oversized one so it makes too much cold.On your other hand your other houses have properly sized ac.